# Get all EoL Windows Computer in AD With Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have to create a script to get all EoL Windows computers in our AD.

This is my Code right now:

```
$getad = Get-ADComputer -Filter {
OperatingSystem -like "Windows 10*"
-or 
OperatingSystem -like "*Windows Vista*"
-or 
OperatingSystem -like "*Windows XP*"
-or 
OperatingSystem -like "*95*" 
-or  
OperatingSystem -like "*94*"     
-or       
OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 8*"      
-or        
OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 8.1*"
-or         
OperatingSystem -like "*2000 Professional*"        
-or            
OperatingSystem -like "*2000 Server*"         
-or           
OperatingSystem -like "*2003*"             
-or            
OperatingSystem -like "*Windows NT*"               
-or           
OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 7*"            
-and 
#Windows8         
OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*6.3.9600*"           
-and 
#Windows7 SP1            
OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*6.1.7601*"             
-and 
#Windows10               
OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*16299*"  
-and 
#Windows10                
OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*14393*"                 
-and 
#Windows10                 
OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*15063*"                
} -Properties ('Name', 'operatingsystem', 'DistinguishedName', 
'description', 'lastlogondate', 'OperatingsystemVersion') 
$selectobj = $getad | Select-Object Name, Operatingsystem, 
DistinguishedName, Description, Lastlogondate, OperatingSystemVersion
$selectobj
```

The problem: The part with `-notlike` is not applied. I get computers with the versions I do not want to see.

I need all EoL Computers in one variable so i can work with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is one of logic with your combination of `or` and `and`, but don't use `-like` and `-notlike` they don't work the way you think. Use the regular expression switches `-imatch` and `-inotmatch` like this:

```
OperatingSystem -imatch "Windows 10|Windows Vista|Windows XP|95|94|Windows 8|2000|2003|Windows NT|Windows 7"
-and OperatingSystemVersion -inotmatch "6.3.9600|6.1.7601|16299|14393"
```

Comment: If i use     -imatch instead of -like i get an error. I've replaced my     -like and     -notlike part with the     -imatch and     -inotmatch. But now i get the error:  'Operator Not supported: -imatch'

Answer (score 0):

I added ( and ) and now it works.

```
 $getad = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 10*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*16299*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*14393*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*15063*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows Vista*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows XP*") -or  (operatingsystem -like "*95*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*94*") -or ( operatingsystem -like "*Windows 8*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*9600*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Professional*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Server*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2003*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows NT*") -or ( operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*7601*")} -Properties ('Name', 'operatingsystem', 'DistinguishedName', 'description', 'lastlogondate', 'OperatingsystemVersion', 'Created', 'Enabled', 'SamAccountName')

 $selectobj = $getad | Select-Object Name, Operatingsystem, DistinguishedName, Description, Lastlogondate, OperatingSystemVersion, Created, Enabled, SamAccountName
```

It works but it isn't nice at all because of its lenght.
Is there any other shorter way?